# SSL Error while trying to login facebook with my app

Tags: facebook, ssl

I have integrated Facebook with my application which is hosted on websphere. But  when I am trying to login with myapplication I am getting follwoing error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake

Please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am trying to add graph.facebook.com as a host in my was console. I got error in my console. what to do? Please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you out. Do you have any implementation code? have you configured correctly your Facebook Application Settings? What happens if you inspect the request on your Browser Development tools? Which url is giving you this SSL response?